# Userlist On project select Using Jquery Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, jira

Iam using Jira and need to populate the list of users for project selected.

```
  <td><select  id="projectsList" class="textFld" multiple="multiple"></select></td>
      <td><select id="userList" class="textFld"multiple="multiple" ></select></td>
```

Written Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){  getAllProjectsList();
$("#projectsList").change(function() {
    var projKey = $("#projectsList").val();
    if (projKey.length > 0) {
        getAllUsersList(projKey);
    }
});
});

function getAllProjectsList() { $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "http://server/issues/rest/api/2/project",

      success: function(projectsList){
                var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
                $.each(projectsList, function(index, item) {
                    htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';
                    });
                $("#projectsList").html(htmlContent);
                 }
```

});
}

I got list of all project from server.Now i need to get list of all user for selected project[multi project].

```
    function getAllUsersList(projKey) {  var proj= $("#projectsList option:selected").text();$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
path : "http:/server/issues/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?jql=project=proj AND  startAt=0 AND maxResults=500 AND username=%",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "text",
      success: function(userList){
                var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
                $.each(userList, function(index, item){
                 var userId = item.UserID;
                htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';

                    });
                $("#userList").html(htmlContent);
                    }                           });   }
```

getting list as undefined......
Any help..??

Comment: What the heck is this `http:/server/issues/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?jql=project=proj AND  startAt=0 AND maxResults=500 AND username=%` ? Is it valid to pass query string parameters like this ? Don't think so. Could you add an error callback to your ajax req and check if you are getting any errors.

Comment: No error at console...But userlist was undefined...so to get the user list based on project selected..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass query string parameters.And the userlist was working.

```
    function getAllUsersList(projectKey) {  $.ajax({


  type : 'GET',url: 'http://server/issues/rest/api/2/user/assignable/search?project='+projectKey+'&startat=0&maxresults=500&username=%',

      success: function(userList){

                var htmlContent = '<option value="">Select-One</option>';
                $.each(userList, function(index, item){
                 var userId = item.UserID;
                htmlContent += '<option value="' + item.key + '">' + item.key + '</option>';

                    });
                $("#userList").html(htmlContent);
                    }
```

});
}